# Which military uniforms are shown in these photos?

Tags: united-states, identification, uniform, infantry

[image][image]

It's a large tintype.  He was in the 5th Infantry and the 16th Infantry. He joined the Army in 1858 and in 1869 then joined the Navy and was aboard the [U.S.S. Lancaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Lancaster_(1858)) until 1871. (Ignore the 1858 date on the first photo).

Comment: I could be wrong but that looks like a Model 1840 dragoon sabre.  The branch insignia on the hat looks to be infantry (possibly artillery.)

Answer (score 1):

Top image he's wearing the 1859 regulation marine corps dress uniform with horstmann epaulettes which was used into the 1870s. Bottom is a cavalry uniform with the mounted service jacket. The style and cut of his cavalry uniform dates it to the late 1860s when that specific image was made.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that the upper photo is of a sergeant, probably artillery, of a state militia unit.  Frock coats of regular USA enlisted men of the period were single breasted not double.

And the lower photo appears to be a light artillery uniform circa the US Civil War.
Neither appear to be infantry uniforms, either regular or militia.